# adding certificate in cell truststore through unix

Tags: unix, ssl, websphere

I have executed below unix commands to add certificate in node truststore on websphere 7.0. 
Can you please help me how can I add certificate in cell truststore.

I executed the below commands:
 was70nd -profile  cert_add (key | trust) [-n ]
      [-pwd ] -signer -alias  -f

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's "was70nd"? A shell script? We don't know what's in it.

Comment: Please follow this guideline that can help to add a signer certificate http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSN2Y_2.0.0.4/com.ibm.tsiem.doc/esguide/webspheree2.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add the certificate through the WAS Admin Console. Go to following Location

**Menu --> Security --> SSL certificate and key management --> click on Key stores and certificates --> click on the desired truststore --> click on the Signer certificates**.

From here you can import your certificate into the WebSphere truststore.